# Changing href of <a> Not working

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink

I want to change the href of  tag using jquery.

This is the html code:

```
<a href="exampleurl" id="a_theme"  onClick="return activate_theme();">Click</a>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
function activate_theme(){
  $("#a_theme")).attr("href", "new url");
}
```

It displays an error :

```
activate_theme is not defined
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your function (there is an extra closing paren in your jQuery selector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st way:

```
$(function(){
$("#a_theme").click(
    function(){
        $("#a_theme").attr("href", "new url");
    }
);
});

<a href="#" id="a_theme">Click</a>
```

2nd way:

```
function activate_theme(){
    $("#a_theme").attr("href", "new url");
}


<a href="#" id="a_theme" onClick="activate_theme()">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, probably because `activate_theme()` is defined in a scope inaccessible from your `onClick` handler. You have also a syntax mistake (double `)` in jQuery call).

Just replace your code with this:

```
<a href="exampleurl" id="a_theme">Click</a>
```

and with JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#a_theme").attr("href", "new url");
});
```

which will be executed as soon as DOM is ready, and will replace `href` for specified link.

See working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/mHtHc/

Answer (score 0):

```
try with this also:

$('#a_theme').click(function(){
 $(this).attr('href', 'new_url');
});
```

but if you have more then one id with the same name then :

```
$('#a_theme').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).click(function(){
     //same url on all '#a_theme' on click
     $(this).attr('href', 'new_url');
    });
});
```